# Unknown tag: user-reference

Tags: discussion

I was just looking at [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111389/creating-a-user-reference-field-based-on-a-similar-field-on-a-referenced-node) that is tagged with the [`user-reference`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-reference) tag.

I'm not sure what this tag means. It doesn't seem to relate to any module and doesn't have a description.

Should it just be a synonym of the [`entity-reference`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-reference) tag?

Is there a generally accepted way of finding the meaning of tags that you don't know (other than just Googling it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Reference is part of the [References module](https://drupal.org/project/references) (now all but deprecated).

It shouldn't be a synonym of entity ref, there's some overlap but the way they operate is very different.

A Google search for "drupal user_reference" turn up References as the top hit, so I'd go with that :)

Comment: Got ya - I saw the References module but didn't know it was related.